# Android: how can I test the "Open With" feature on an emulator if legally I can't install multiple apps that will trigger the Open With window?

Tags: android

As the title states.

How would you tackle this?

I don't feel like hacking Android to install the marketplace & multiple apps.

But on the other hand, I do have to test the "Open With" feature of my application, which I'm currently unable to trigger as there are no 2 same apps to open some sort of file.

Note: I don't have a real phone with me.

Code that I'm referring to is this (when a user clicks a file):

```
    ...
    Intent intnt = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(f);

    String mime = General.getMimeType(full_path);
    intnt.setDataAndType(uri, mime);

    intnt.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    try {
        startActivity(intnt);

    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, 
            "No Application Available to View ...", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    finish();
```

Basicaly the problem is that currently when I click an image/music file, the app automatically starts (no Open WIth window).

And I can't disable the default app for these files as they're the only applications that can run them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mime type `*/*` and it will show you the open with window:

```
intnt.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
```

with all installed applications.

Comment: Wow, this is creative & it takes 5 seconds. Solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Create a test application that responds to an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for the desired MIME type, and install it on the device.

Or, find open source applications that can respond to an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for the desired MIME type, and install those on the device.